# Parametric equation of a spring in geogebra

Tags: reference-request, parametric

I'm looking for help to understand how to find the parametric equations of this spring drawn in geogebra. Here's the link of the geogebra file which represents the perfect spring I was looking for, where I can move one or both ends of the spring to change its length and its coils width
https://www.geogebra.org/m/AtDTCQGw.

The formula I don't understand is $curve(x(A)+(Lt+r+rcos(\pi-wt))e_1-2rsin(\pi-wt)e_2, y(A)+(Lt+r+rcos(\pi-wt))e_2+2rsin(\pi-wt)e_1, t, 0, 1)$.

The problem is not the curve command itself, but the parametric equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=x(A)+(Lt+r+rcos(\pi-wt))e_1-2rsin(\pi-wt)e_2 \\ 
y=y(A)+(Lt+r+rcos(\pi-wt))e_2+2rsin(\pi-wt)e_1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Most of all I'd like to understand how I can write the parametric equations of a curve (2D or 3D) in general case, simply looking at the drawing of the curve and I'd like to have some good resources at undergrad level (textbooks, preferably) where I can find this information.

Thanks